# How can I exclude an object from my array so a foreach loop avoids it?

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api

I'm using a foreach loop to get images from the graph API in facebook.

Here is the return from my json decode:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Person 1",
         "id": "12345678",
         "picture": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/123456789_123456_789456.jpg"
      },
      {
         "name": "Person 2",
         "id": "12345679",
         "picture": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/123456789_123456_789457.jpg"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=.....&fields=name,id,picture&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=..."
   }
}
```

Here's my PHP:

```
        $url  = "https://graph.facebook.com/". $uid ."/friends?access_token=". $access_token ."&fields=name,id,picture";
        $users = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

        echo $access_token .'<br><br>';

        foreach ($users as $name => $value) {
            foreach ($value as $entry) {
                //Loop for profile pics
                if ($entry->picture) {
                    echo '<a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=' . $entry->id . '" target="_blank">' . '<img src="'. $entry->picture . '" class="profile-thumb' . $entry->name . '" id="'. $entry->id .'"></a>';
                }
            }
        }
```

This is fine as it pulls the paths to the images correctly, but it gives me this error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\feref.com\facebook\test-app\friends.php on line 50
```

Which I assume is as a result of the 'paging' object in the array.

How can I prevent this error? That is, how can I exclude the 'paging' object from my loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `if (isset($this->picture))` instead. That'll test if the picture property exists at all.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than iterating over your entire result, only iterate over the data array.

Add this line after you declare $users;

```
$data = $users->('data');
```

Then do

```
foreach($data as $entry){
    if(isset($entry->picture)){
        echo ...
    }
}
```